# fruit_pwrite_meta_netatalk: ad_pwrite failed - Time Machine backup over SMB

Tags: macos, ubuntu, samba, timemachine

I'm trying to use SMB for Time Machine backups. I'm currently using macOS 10.15.5, Samba 4.11.6-Ubuntu and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

This is my conf:

```
[timemachine]
   comment = Time Machine
   path = /mnt/HD/Backup/timemachine
   browseable = yes
   writeable = yes
   create mask = 0600
   directory mask = 0700
   spotlight = yes
   vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
   fruit:aapl = yes
   fruit:time machine = yes
   fruit:time machine max size = 750G
```

I can successfully register the share as time machine disk but when it tries to backup I get this error:

```
[2020/07/17 05:53:28.442317,  0] ../../source3/modules/vfs_fruit.c:4637(fruit_pwrite_meta_netatalk)
  fruit_pwrite_meta_netatalk: ad_pwrite [071FEBFA-ACF7-5694-9FB6-A02D91AE7861.sparsebundle:AFP_AfpInfo] failed
```

If I mount the share via Finder I can successfully create file and folder.

Do you have any clue?
Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue (although with docker image `mbentley/timemachine:smb`). Did you figure it out?

Comment: @Geir I solved compiling samba from source (master branch) and following the instructions reported here (https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_Samba_to_Work_Better_with_Mac_OS_X)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. Looks like it's a bug in samba, and it's fixed in smb 4.17.5.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).